# JAVA_HOME with JDK8 and JDK9

Tags: java, java-8, java-9, system-variable

For some reasons I need to use JDK8 and JDK9. Is a good idea to put both paths (to JDK8 and JDK9) into the same JAVA_HOME system environment's variable?

Details: I need to run both systems at the same time, one with ant (which uses jdk8) and second with maven (which uses jdk9).

Comment: explain what you are trying to do, why do you think you need both?

Comment: obviously, you can't use both at the same time, are you asking about switching between them?

Comment: Yes - about switching but without big effort. I need to run both systems at the same time, one with ant (which uses jdk8) and second with maven (which uses jdk9)

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend to set `JAVA_HOME` to Java 8 and [use the `.mavenrc` file to launch Maven with Java 9](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/maven-on-java-9/#The-mavenrc-File).

Comment: Just set the `JAVA_HOME` before you run the `ANT` Task then set it again before running the `MAVEN` Task

Comment: @Kenneth Clark - just what I thought, but then realised that it is annoying to switch paths every time I need to rebuild both projects.

Comment: Potential third option: use only JDK 9 and have one build produce Java 8 compatible classes. You can say "for some reasons" but if you don't explain what those reasons are, its hard to really know what the true limitations are.

Comment: My limitation at the moment is ant. I tried to run it with jdk9 with no success.

Comment: I think @Nicolai's answer is what you want. Your ant build shouldn't fail *because of* jdk9, it seems more likely that there are issues with your code or build configuration which is causing the build to fail.

Comment: @Czarcik seems like valuable information to add to the question.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question about your trouble running Ant.  I have done a full Ant build with Java 9 literally hundreds of times.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that path is reserved for the current active java command keyword in the command line interface. You can't have multiple JDK active at the same time at any moment when using the terminal. So it is not a good idea.

You can however point the JAVA_HOME to the folder where you have multiple JDK installations and then set the PATH variable to a certain JDK. So when you want to change the JDK you change only the PATH variable and leave JAVA_HOME as it is.

If you intend to use different JDK across multiple projects in an IDE, then yes you can have multiple JDK and you can chose the JDK you want to use in the Project Settings.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you then I would create function() in `.profile` or `.bashrc` for command prompt or terminal which will export `JAVA_HOME` variable to `Java8` or `Java9` depending on whether I am running `ant` or `mvn` respectively.

Lets say your Java8 and Java9 are installed at below locations ...

- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin
- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0_4\bin

Then your functions in `.profile` or `.bashrc` should be like this ...

For `ant` and Java8 (here i am passing command line argument `$1` to `ant` command)...

```
runant() {
  export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin";
  ant $1;
}
```

For `mvn` and Java9 ...

```
runmvn() {
  export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0_4\bin";
  mvn clean install;
}
```

With the above functions, you can run `ant` and `mvn` from command prompt and `JAVA_HOME` will be set appropriately ONLY for that specific run.